# In Google Analytics how do I determine which pages are losing page views month over month?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, statistics, page-views

How do I  show and order the pages which lost views (popularity) in Google Analytics?

e.g. page A lost 350 unique visitors this month and page B lost 300, etc.

Comment: Not exactly what you want but you can go to `Behavior > Site Content > All Pages` Then you can check monthly/weekly stats of each popular page on your website. That's what I do.

Comment: when i make changes on sam page i wonder if they are good or not for it. So afther month i  would like to check if stats grov or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to track just a few pages or a section (/blog/) and not all I would recommend setting up Custom Intelligent Event alert with a threshold. Below is a screenshot of what something like that would look like:

[image]

Its not 100% what you want but it should give you a better automated option.

Otherwise, you can just pull up pages in Behavior - All pages and using date ranges for this months + previous period. If you are interested in a particular page then you can filter it. This approach will also give you a +/- multiple metrics:

[image]

Comment: THX ! Second metod so simple and enough